# Return global value from function to class

Tags: php, class, return

How can i return global $here $that $this to my new2()

```
new1()
{
 global $that;
 global $this;//every global will return
 global $here;
 $here="true";
 return $here;
}   
new2($here)
{
       //i dont have $here
}
class Main {
    public function parametr(){ 
        new1();
        new2($here)

    }
```

Comment: See my answer as I explained everything with your code.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't have function `new()`, so I replaced it with `new_()`. Secondly, if you want to use global `$here` instead of local, you need to add `global $here` in the beginning of the function. So the code would be looking like:

```
$here = '';
function new_() {
     global $here;
     $here = "true";
     return $here;
}   
function new2() {
    global $here;
    echo $here;
}
new_();
new2();
```

**Update:** Also you can't pass `$here` in Main class because you didn't declared it is global `$here`, so it is taking the local `$here` which is empty. Same with declaring function with parameter `$here` in `new2()`, you can't add the parameter if you want global `$here`, because it will take the local here.

Comment: why i cant have funtion new() in my public function in class

Comment: @user3397383 - You can't have function `new()` because `new` is a reserved word in PHP: it's used when you instantiate a class

Comment: As @MarkBaker stated. If you want to know which words are also reserved by PHP, look it up http://us3.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php